# What does "tired of her ass" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Does it mean tired of her or tired of having sex with her?

Comment: It can mean either, depending on context, but you haven’t given any, so there’s no way to give an answer as it stands.

Comment: Without context, it could also mean *tired of her* ***mule***.

Comment: @JasonBassford Only donkeys are asses; mules are half-assed equine hybrids. :)

Answer (score 4):

Without further context, it is difficult to answer your question. But I'll give it a go.

One possible meaning (the most likely one) is that "her ass" is being used as to refer to "her" as a whole. In other words, the write is saying that he's "tired of her". A part of "her" (her "ass" or bottom) is being used as a stand-in for "her" person as a whole. This is an example of the literary tool known as *synecdoche*.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche

Of course, you should note that this is a rather crude and highly informal example.

Another possible meaning is sexual, although this would be an uncommon construction. A more explicit construction where the sexual meaning is overt would be (for instance) "tired of shagging (or banging) that ass".

More context would be very helpful.

Comment: Another example of its use as a synecdoche would be "Get your ass in here" as a more vehement "Get in here"

Comment: @user888379 I'm partial to "Get your ass to Mars!" from the original Total Recall (the only version that counts in my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily I believe this saying in the U.S is implying "Sick of her" or "Had enough of her".

Answer (score 0):

Very much irked by her, it seems to be...